# Thom Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I have a question about an argument in a proof from J.P. May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" (page 196):

[image]

We use following notations: Let $\zeta: E \to B$ be a $n$-vector bundle and $Sph(E)$ the sphere bundle of $E$.

Denote by $T \zeta := Sph(E)/B$ the Thom space obtained by quotient out $B$ embedded as section (compare with constuction at p. 194).

NOW THE PROBLEM:

Applying Serre spectral sequence to the sphere bundle $Sph(E) \to B$ with fiber $S^n$ we deduce that $$H^*(Sph(E);R) \cong H^*(B;R) \otimes H^*(S^n;R)$$ as stated in the excerpt.

Then May says that we obtain $$\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R) \cong H^*(B;R) \otimes H^*(S^n;R)$$

by the canonical quotient map $ Sph(E) \to T \zeta$.

I don't understand this argument. Does $ H^*(Sph(E);R) \cong \tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R)$ hold? Why?

Remark:
Here the full book: [A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/maybook.pdf)

Comment: That is not what May says.  He says we obtain $\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R)\cong H^*(B;R)\otimes H^n(S^n;R)$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: sorry, I have overseen the "reduced" symbol. But following point stays unsolved: Firstly Serre-sequence argument shows $H^*(Sph(E);R) \cong H^*(B;R) \otimes H^*(S^n;R)$. Futhermore taking into account the definition of reduced cohomology we have $\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R)= H^*(Sph(E);B)$ induced by fibration $Sph(E) \to B$. That's ok. But I don't see how May combine these two arguments to get $\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R)\cong H^*(B;R)\otimes H^n(S^n;R)$.

Comment: The main difference is not the tilde but that it's $H^n(S^n;R)$, not $H^*(S^n;R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then May says that we obtain $H^*(T \zeta;R) \cong H^*(B;R) \otimes H^*(S^n;R)$

No, that's not what he says.  What he says is we obtain $\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta;R)\cong H^*(B;R)\otimes H^n(S^n;R)$.  Note that $$H^*(Sph(\zeta))\cong  H^*(B) \otimes H^*(S^n) \cong (H^*(B)\otimes H^0(S^n))\oplus (H^*(B)\otimes H^n(S^n))$$ (the coefficients of $R$ are omitted for brevity) and moreover that the restriction map $H^*(Sph(\zeta))\to H^*(B)$ can be identified with the projection onto the first summand $H^*(B)\otimes H^0(S^n)\cong H^*(B)$.  It then follows from the long exact sequence on cohomology associated to the cofiber sequence $B\to Sph(\zeta)\to T\zeta$ that the map $Sph(\zeta)\to T\zeta$ induces an isomorphism between $\tilde{H}^*(T\zeta)$ and the second summand $H^*(B)\otimes H^n(S^n)$.

Comment: ...yesss since $H^q(B) \to \tilde{H}^{q+1}(T\zeta)$ in this sequence is in all degrees a zero map by the section argument,right? Thank you!

Comment: Yes since the previous map is surjective.